# JavaScript Array + Array = String?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When you try to add an Array to another Array in JavaScript, it turns it into a String. Typically when this operation is performed in another languages, the lists are combined.

**JavaScript**

```
[1, 2] + [3, 4] = "1,23,4"
```

**Python**

```
[1, 2] + [3, 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm not trying to start a flame war about which language is better. But JavaScript's makes no sense to me. Is there a logical reason for why JavaScript does this? Or is it just a quirk of the language?

Comment: The `+` operator can add numbers or concatenate strings, and it prefers strings. Anything that's not a string is coerced to a string somehow, and for objects that's done by calling `.toString()`. (I wouldn't call structured adding of array elements "typical" either.)

Comment: If you think this is bizarre enough, take a look at this video: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat :P

Comment: Your comment about the `language flame war` is irrelevant to the question. Just because it's different doesn't mean it's better or worse

Comment: It's not obvious that the result should be a concatenation of the arrays. In my mind the result would just as likely be `[4, 6]` (adding the terms) as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. JavaScript makes you explicitly ask for concatenation: `([1, 2]).concat([3, 4])` which reads nicely, and isn't ambiguous at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript(JS) has quite a few 'quirks' to put it mildly. To get the behavior you desire, you can use the `concat` method. `[1, 2].concat([3, 4])`

The source of the confusion is, as Douglas Crockford says in his excellent book, "JavaScript: The Good Parts" arrays in JS are "Phony Arrays", (they do not do a linear allocation of memory among other things). They are actually objects with Array like characteristics which they inherit from Array.prototype. This is both good and bad, so beware.

In fact he puts JS arrays in the "Awful Parts" of JS section, where all problematic things in JS which cannot be easily avoided, are relegated to.

Answer (score 3):

[This is how the Addition Operator (+) is defined..](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1)

The `+` operator does *not* have a "special meaning/overload" for other value types (like arrays) and the behavior in ECMAScript is independent of the behavior in any other language.

> The production AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>      Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim). See the Note below 11.6.3.

The conversion in this case is rather subtle, but is the result of the array values, being Objects without a corresponding primitive type, having "toString" invoked as a result of the `[ToPrimitive]` operation. As such the rule application is approximately as follows.

```
   [1,2] + [3,4]
-> [1,2].toString() + [3,4].toString()     // Rules #5 and #6
-> "1,2" + "3,4"                           // Rule #7
-> "1,23,4"
```